# Set volume size in Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hey I am deploying my multi container docker env via elastic beanstalk.

My docker-compose.yml has an entry like

```
service:
    image: redis
    volumes:
        - redisdata:/data
volumes:
    redisdata:
```

By this the contents of redisdata are persited to disk and "survive" deploys.

On the dockerrun.aws.json side this leads to

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "redis",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/data",
                    "sourceVolume": "Redisdata"
                }
            ],
            "name": "redis"
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "redisdata"
            },
            "name": "Redisdata"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now my problem:

```
ec2-instance $ df -h
/dev/xvda1      7,8G    7,7G     0  100% /
/dev/dm-3        99G     89M   94G    1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2d33cb679881808fac34182bfbec8feb57bf5f65c81c51b52c3f6c9917541040
```

the created volume `redisdata` has only 7,7 GB size,  where as the main root file system of the redis container gets 99 GB. This is the consequence of such named volumes being mounted to `/var/app/current/redisdata` on the ec2 instance, and this folder is just part of the 8 GB root mount.
How can I add a size spec to Dockerrun.aws.json ?

I have seen the option to specify "standard" mount points in Dockerrun.aws.json, but how can I make sure the source dir is created and also that it has enough space?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found up to now is by altering an ebextension config file.

I created a file `.ebextensions/bla.config` with the content

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: RootVolumeSize
    value: "100"
```

By this, the root volume of the docker containers will have 100 GB.

**Caution:** Deploying this additional file will wipe your ec2 instance, any data on the ec2 instance (inlcuding docker volumes) is lost!

**Edit: Additional solution adding an external EBS device**
This is what I got from the AWS support:

> By following above steps, external EBS device can be added
>   successfully to mount it to the docker containers. Also, I suggest you
>   to consider the option of using Elastic File System (EFS) for
>   persistent storage. The advantage with EFS is that it's storage
>   capacity is elastic and the data will be persistent even if the
>   environments EC2 instance gets terminated unexpectedly. Here is the
>   blog [6] which provides steps to mount the EFS volume to an Elastic
>   Beanstalk environment instance.
>
> Below is the .ebextensions config file to add external EBS device (of
>   size 30GB) to the beanstalk environment's instance. You can also add
>   EBS volume with the snapshot.

```
[root@ip-172-31-21-181 multi-dockerapp]# cat .ebextensions/ebs.config commands:   
01mkfs:
    command: "mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdh"   02mkdir:
    command: "mkdir /media/volume1"   03mount:
    command: "mount /dev/sdh /media/volume1"
option_settings:   
    aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
        InstanceType: t2.large
        EC2KeyName: eks
        MonitoringInterval: "1 minute"
        IamInstanceProfile: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
        BlockDeviceMappings: "/dev/sdh=:30,/dev/sdj=snap-51eef269"
```

> Below is the snippet of 'Dockerrun.aws.json' file which create volume
>   with sourcePath as '/media/volume1'

```
[root@ip-172-31-21-181 multi-dockerapp]# cat Dockerrun.aws.json 
{   "AWSEBDockerrunVersion":

2,   "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "php-app",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/media/volume1"
      }
    },
    ....
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        .....
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "php-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/www/html"
        }
      ]
    } }
```